# Meaning of src_dir ?= src in makeifle

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am new to makfile.
what is the meaning of ?= in makefile 
  Dose it mean if not defined then define or its something else

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means "define if not defined". From `info make`:

> There is another assignment operator for variables, `?='.  This is
>   called a conditional variable assignment operator, because it only has
>   an effect if the variable is not yet defined.